# How can I remove an object instance from within itself

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a little game using pygame, and I want to delete objects that have disappeared off screen. What I thought of doing is

```
class Projectile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, path, move_speed, x_pos, y_pos):
        super().__init__()         
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def move(self):
        if self.rect.y < 0:
            del self
```

but that doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Where are you storing the objects?

Comment: @jwodder in a group, that I later get a list of the sprites from and iterate on it. I solved my problem by now though.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution to this.

In my game loop I did

```
for projectile in projectile_group.sprites():
    if projectile.rect.y < 0:
        projectile.kill()
```

and it kills off any projectiles that are off screen.